# How to get size of an image that is held in a byte array in KB

Tags: java, android

I want to find out the size of an image that is held in a byte array in KB

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mPicture);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
```

The following logs display two different results for an image that is **11.7KB**:

```
Log.d(TAG, "bm size: " + bm.getByteCount()/1024); // 942
Log.d(TAG, "baos size: " + baos.size()/1024); // 81
Log.d(TAG, "byte size: " + b.length/1024); // 81
```

Which is the correct result or how do I get the correct result?? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

`bm.getByteCount()/1024 // 942` is the original size of your image

`baos.size()/1024 // 81` is the size after the image has been compressed

The first gives the size of bitmap which represents the **original image resource** but the next two give the size of the stream or the byte array representing the **compressed** one. So the first one returns a bigger value than the next two.

Comment: how do you explain the size being different to the actual image size. its supposed to be 11.7KB but its returning something different as you can see...

Comment: 11.7KB is the size of the compressed file you opened. Once it is loaded as a Bitmap, its size is uncompressed, so its size is proportional to width*height. Then you are compressing to JPEG with a compression factor of 100 which results in a size of 81. This is different than the original probably because the original was compressed with a compression of 60-80 instead of 100.